# Why is TreeMap taking value as key

Tags: java, tree, comparator, treemap

I have taken a treemap and want to sort it according to its key values which are stored in a hashmap.
Whenever I want to update a key-value pair, I remove the key from the tree and add the key value again.

But I discovered that when I insert a key value pair, the key is getting overwritten if I insert a key-value pair where the value is already present. and moreover, the key has multiple occurrences in the treemap which should not happen.
Can someone please explain to me what is happening?

```
class StockPrice {
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
    TreeMap<Integer,Integer> treemap=new TreeMap<>((k1,k2)->map.get(k1)-map.get(k2)); //min heap
    int latesttime=-1;
    
    public StockPrice() {
        
    }
    
    public void update(int timestamp, int price) {
        System.out.println(treemap);
        latesttime=Math.max(latesttime,timestamp);
        map.put(timestamp,price);
        if(treemap.containsKey(timestamp)){
            treemap.remove((Integer)timestamp);
        }
        treemap.put(timestamp,price);
    }
    
    public int current() {
        return map.get(latesttime);
    }
    
    public int maximum() {
        return map.get(treemap.lastKey());
    }
    
    public int minimum() {
        return map.get(treemap.firstKey());
    }
}
```

```
["StockPrice","update","update","minimum","maximum","update","maximum","maximum","current","update","current","minimum","update","update","minimum","minimum"]
[[],[38,2308],[43,121],[],[],[40,5339],[],[],[],[32,5339],[],[],[43,6414],[49,9369],[],[]]

The output of print statement in the update method.
{}
{38=2308}
{43=121, 38=2308}
{43=121, 38=2308, 40=5339}
{43=121, 38=2308, 32=5339}
{43=121, 38=2308, 32=5339, 43=6414}
```

I wanted the values to be overwritten and not the key.

Comment: Read the Javadoc for `TreeMap`, and understand what the `Comparator` does.

Comment: How can a treeMap contain duplicated key values?

Comment: You don't need the `containsKey()/remove()` code. `TreeMap.put()` does that anyway. Don't keep a dog and bark yourself.

Comment: @user207421 , if i remove the containsKey() and remove() function from above , it will give different results.

Comment: It seems like , when i am updating a key-value pair, the value pair is not getting rearranged in the tree.

Comment: That's just further evidence of the same Comparator bug.

Comment: Why did the treeMap.remove() did not remove the key value pair 43=121.

Comment: *Because of your `Comparator` bug.* It violates the contract. See @BasilBourque's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Your `Comparator` compares keys by value from first map, *not* by their own content

You have specified a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html), but apparently misunderstand how that `Comparator` is being put to work.

Your comparator compares keys of the second map by the value returned from first map — *not* the content of those keys

Let's look at a simpler example.

We start with three names, each mapped to a number. Notice that two of them map to the same number coincidentally. Both Alice and Carol return `2`.

```java
Map < String, Integer > otherMap =
        Map.of(
                "Alice" , 2 ,
                "Bob" , 3 ,
                "Carol" , 2
        );
```

Let's dump to console with a call the `Map#toString`. Be aware that [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) iterates in an arbitrary order at any random time. By definition, a `Map` is unsorted.

> otherMap.toString() = {Bob=3, Alice=2, Carol=2}

Now we define a second map. But this map is a [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html), so its keys are kept in sorted order. The sorting by default is their [*natural order*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html). Alternatively, we can specify a `Comparator`, as done here.

We use [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) as the concrete class for our `NavigableMap`.

```java
NavigableMap < String, Integer > navMap = new TreeMap <>( ( k1 , k2 ) -> otherMap.get( k1 ) - otherMap.get( k2 ) );
```

By the way, that lambda can be replaced with a method reference passed to [`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)). This is beside the point here, just FYI.

```java
NavigableMap < String, Integer > navMap = new TreeMap <>( Comparator.comparingInt( otherMap :: get ) );
```

By whichever of the two syntaxes, the effect is the same:  Keys in our *second* map are judged by the value of the matching entry in the *first* map.

This means putting "Alice" in our second map has the same effect as putting "Carol" in our second map. Both return a value from the first map of `2`. So they are equivalent.

Let's add three entries to our new map.

```java
navMap.put( "Alice" , 100 );
navMap.put( "Bob" , 200 );
navMap.put( "Carol" , 300 );
```

Apparently you would expect *three* entries in `navMap`. But, no, there are *two* entries in `navMap`.

> navMap = {Alice=300, Bob=200}

You can see that [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/8CBawt).

Putting "Carol" updated the entry for "Alice" with the new value of `300`, rather than make a new third entry. This is because  you told the `TreeMap` to compare the two keys based on their coincidentally shared value of `2` as returned by the first `Map`. You overrode the default behavior of comparing the text of "Alice" and "Carol".

Not a bug, a feature. Working as documented.

Pop quiz: What if we changed the `put` lines, so that we put Carol before Alice?

```java
navMap.put( "Carol" , 300 );
navMap.put( "Alice" , 100 );
navMap.put( "Bob" , 200 );
```

Result is `Carol=100` rather than `Alice=300`:

> navMap.toString() = {Carol=100, Bob=200}

What happened is:

1. We made a new entry into our empty navigable map for "Carol"+300.
2. We attempted to put "Alice"+100. In doing so, the `TreeMap` did a lookup on the first map, and retrieved the value `2` for the key `Alice`. Well, `2` matches the `2` returned by a lookup for our first entry’s key, `Carol`. So that means `Alice` & `Carol` keys are equivalent. So no need for a new entry. The `TreeMap` updates the existing, singular, entry of "Carol"+300 to be "Carol"+100.
3. We put "Bob"+200, with the key of "Bob" returning a value from the first map of `3`. Our `TreeMap` has not seen a key whose comparator value is `3`, meaning it does not equal the `2` of the first and only entry. So the `TreeMap` makes a new second entry of "Bob"+200. Three is bigger than two, so the Bob entry sorts after the Carol entry.

---

Another issue: Your comparator violates the advice in the `TreeMap` Javadoc to make the comparator *consistent with equals*. So you are failing to obey the general contract of the *Map* interface.

---

I have no idea what you were trying to accomplish in your original effort behind this Question. I suggest you post another Question with your original goal so the community can devise an entirely different approach without what seems like an overly complicated  use of double maps.

Comment: I wanted to sort the the treemap according to the values and not key and there for I made a hashmap that stores that key value pair , and when I try to add any key value pair to the treemap , the comparator method reads the value associated to the key from the hasamap.